# How to fix a layout error in Checkout when using Pay with Amazon with WooCommerce on my wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce

I am trying to set up a woo commerce store for my website and I want to use amazon as the payment method. Everything was going fine until I tried to test it and order something myself with my own amazon account. When I am in the checkout page, the Billing Method and Address are displayed wrong. It's like they are over to the left to far and cut off in the middle of the amazon content. My wordpress theme is woo commerce compatible. Please help!

Comment: we cant unless you post code or at least a link to see what is going on. This is actually a site for coding rather than general help, you might just want to hire a developer ? it wouldn't cost much to get a simple design flaw fixed.

Comment: I agree with David. This is definitely theme related. You should reach out to WooThemes (plug-in developer) if the plug-in is supposed to work with all WooCommerce compatible themes.